# “Brightness is bright” or “brightness is high”

Tags: semantics

Can “Brightness is bright” mean brightness is high? I googled it, but I got a little bit of information. In my native language, “brightness is bright” is often used.

https://forum.fairphone.com/t/lowest-brightness-is-too-bright/53784

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The phrase, "brightness is bright" is meaningless. "The lowest brightness level of my phone is too bright" makes perfect sense. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @gotube I’m asking about “the lowest brightness of my phone is too bright” but I wonder why you put “level” into it.

Comment: In the context of an informal comment about an electronic screen the comment is perfectly understandable. It would be more 'correct' to say something like "Even at its lowest brightness setting, I find the screen too bright".

Comment: No, this makes no sense, informally or formally. If someone told me, "Brightness is bright," I'd laugh. "No kidding, dude. Blackness is black, too." You need "level" in there, because otherwise you're talking about brightness itself, not the brightness level on a phone!

Answer (score 1):

Typically we'd say "the brightness of my phone is high".

As Felinius comically pointed out, saying "my brightness is bright" is kind of a tautology. You can say "my brightness level is bright" or "I find my phone's brightness to be too bright".